# CakePHP 3 - Saving entity field FLOAT as INTEGER

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp-3.0

I need to save one field of my entity as an Integer in the database, but in the application it should be seen as Float.

For now, I tried to use methods like beforeSave, beforeMarshal, and so on.
In the database, the field is marked as integer(11). In the entity I put

```
 * @property float $price
```

But still, my entity sees this field as Integer...

In the following code (I put it in the Table class), there's only one place where the var_dump function returns float - it's because of conversion to this type. In every other place, it's integer.

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options) {
    var_dump($entity->get('price'));
    die();
    $entity->set('price', $entity->get('price') * 100);
    return true;
}

public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    $data['price'] = (float) $data['price'];
    var_dump($data);
}

public function beforeRules(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options, $operation)
{
    var_dump($entity->get('price'));
}
public function afterRules(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options, $result, $operation)
{
    var_dump($entity->get('price'));
}
```

Does anyone know how to change it, so I will be saving integers, but reading floats?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you save as INT but want to read as FLOAT.

There are two solutions in my opinion. Imagine we have a Products table/entity.

Either you use the number helper in your templates:

```
<?php echo $this->Number->precision($product->price, 2); ?>
```

Or you create a getter in your entity:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Product extends Entity
{
    protected function _getPrice($price)
    {
        return sprintf("%.2f", $price);
    }
}
?>
```

If the value in the column price 125, it will return `125.00`

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve. I need to save a INT like '12345' and read it as '123.45'. Just to loose the decimal point.